# Add/Skip WHERE CLAUSE based on Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I have the below query that takes a TagId list from table variable and returns the list.

But I need to add that CategoryId WHERE condition only if @Tags has the records.

Is it possible to add a WHERE Condition only if my table variable has records otherwise run the same query with 1=1(Always true) and skip the category filter?

```
DECLARE @TagIdList NVARCHAR(100) = '22,25,47'
DECLARE @Tags TABLE (TagId INT);

WITH CSVtoTable
AS (
    SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(t.val, ',', '</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
    FROM (
        SELECT @TagIdList
        ) AS t(val)
    )
INSERT INTO @Tags (TagId)
SELECT m.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(8000)') AS TagId
FROM CSVtoTable
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData') m(n)

SELECT BookingId
    ,C.CategoryName
FROM Booking B
INNER JOIN Category C ON C.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
WHERE (
        b.IsDeleted = 0
        OR b.IsDeleted IS NULL
        )
 -- Add the below where condition only if @Tags has records, else use 1=1
    AND C.CategoryId IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId
        FROM CategoryXTag con
        WHERE TagId IN (
                SELECT TagId
                FROM @Tags
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately you only need to change the end of your query. If performance is an issue you might want to consider using two branches of an `if` block for each of the two cases even though it's technically possible to squeeze the logic into a single query that doesn't generally optimize as well.

```
AND
(
    C.CategoryId IN (
        SELECT CategoryId
        FROM CategotryXTag
        WHERE TagId IN (
            SELECT TagId
            FROM @Tags
        )
    )
    OR
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Tags) = 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare int @tagcount = (select count(*) from @Tags); 

SELECT BookingId, C.CategoryName
FROM Booking B
INNER JOIN Category C 
        ON C.CategoryId = B.CategoryId 
       AND isnull(b.IsDeleted, 0) = 0 
INNER JOIN CategoryXTag con 
        ON C.CategoryId = con.CategoryId 
INNER JOIN @Tags tags 
        ON tags.TagID = con.TagID
        OR @tagcount = 0;
```

if @tags is empty you might need to put one record in it with a value that would never by used and then or that value

```
if(@tagcount = 0) insert into @tags values (-100); 
or tags.TagID = -100;
```

Comment: I need to pull records which doesn't have entry in CategoryXTag when I dont pass Tag list  . But the query has inner join to that table

Comment: OK you indicate another answer works.  You should give it a check.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify your `where` clause. Instead, you achieve the same logic by filling `@Tags` with every `TagId` from `CategoryXTag` before running your final query if `@Tags` is empty after the initial insert:

```
if ((select count(*) from @Tags) = 0)
  insert into @Tags
  select distinct TagId
  from CategoryXTag;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd declare a variable for the @Tags table:

```
declare @needTagsFilter bit
set @needTagsFilter = case when exists(select 1 from @Tags) then 1 else 0 end
```

and change the where clause like

```
AND (
     (@needTagsFilter = 0) OR 
     (C.CategoryId IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId
      FROM CategoryXTag con
      WHERE TagId IN (
            SELECT TagId
            FROM @Tags
            )
     )
    )
```

COUNT(*) is slower then exists. The downside of adding the count/exists directly to your original query is that SQL server might execute it for all rows.